# is it possible to override the size of a frame when something is inside?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am trying to have two identically sized frames inside a grid, like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpasE.png)
i have control over the frame's size when nothing is in it but when i add something into the frame, i lose control over the size itself and it adapts to the size of stuff placed in it. Any way to control the size of a frame when something is inside it?
[size of frame when something is inside:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjTh6.png)
[when nothing is in the frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DR0rM.png)

```py
from tkinter import *
import random as rn

def value_change(choice):
    global user_choice
    user_choice=choice
    return(user_choice)

user_choice=4
hlavni=Tk()
jmeno=Label(hlavni,text='Kámen, nůžky,papír',font=("arial","20","bold"),justify='center')
jmeno.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

hrac_name=Label(hlavni,text='Hráč',justify="left")
hrac_name.grid(row=1,column=0)
pc_name=Label(hlavni,text="Počítač")
pc_name.grid(row=1,column=1)




hrac_f=Frame(hlavni,relief="ridge",borderwidth=4,width=400,height=400,padx=10,pady=10)
hrac_f.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

""" stuff inside the frame
Volba=Label(hrac_f,text="Zadej svou volbu",font=("arial",10,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=0)
values=Label(hrac_f,text="Vyber: Kámen, Nůžky, Papír",font=("arial",10)).grid(row=1,column=0)

choice_f=Frame(hrac_f)
choice_f.grid(row=3,column=0)

stone=Button(choice_f,text="kámen",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(0))
stone.grid(row=0,column=0)

scissors=Button(choice_f,text="nůžky",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(1))
scissors.grid(row=0,column=1)

paper=Button(choice_f,text="papír",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(2))
paper.grid(row=0,column=2) """


hlavni.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when adding widgets to a frame using `.grid()` or `.pack()`, the size of the frame will be adjusted to fit all the widgets.

To change this default behavior, call `.grid_propagate(0)` or `.pack_propagate(0)` on the frame.

For your case, as `.grid()` is used on those widgets inside `hrac_f` frame, then `hrac_f.grid_propagate(0)` should be called:

```py
...
hrac_f=Frame(hlavni,relief="ridge",borderwidth=4,width=400,height=400,padx=10,pady=10)
hrac_f.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

hrac_f.grid_propagate(0) # disable auto size adjustment when adding widgets using grid()

""" stuff inside the frame """
Volba=Label(hrac_f,text="Zadej svou volbu",font=("arial",10,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=0)
values=Label(hrac_f,text="Vyber: Kámen, Nůžky, Papír",font=("arial",10)).grid(row=1,column=0)

choice_f=Frame(hrac_f)
choice_f.grid(row=3,column=0)

stone=Button(choice_f,text="kámen",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(0))
stone.grid(row=0,column=0)

scissors=Button(choice_f,text="nůžky",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(1))
scissors.grid(row=0,column=1)

paper=Button(choice_f,text="papír",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(2))
paper.grid(row=0,column=2)

hlavni.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use frames to change placement manager like grid to place or pack or vice versa. Like you can fix sizes with place and put them inside whatever you want.
[image: This is image normally.]
[image: This is resized/enlarged.]

```
import tkinter as tk

def value_change(choice):
    global user_choice
    user_choice=choice
    return(user_choice)

user_choice=4
hlavni=tk.Tk()
hlavni.geometry("600x100")#to have enough space to prevent collision.

mainFrame = tk.Frame(hlavni,relief="ridge",borderwidth=4)
#means that. start at parents x and y beginning. Have height of parents %95 height(hlavni, main window in this case.)
#have %50 width of parent(hlavni) width. If parent width is 800 width then this mainframe has 400 pixel width
#we set width 600 in this example so our mainframe widget has 300 width.
mainFrame.place(relx=0,rely=0,relheight=0.95,relwidth=0.5)

jmeno=tk.Label(mainFrame,text='Kámen, nůžky,papír',font=("arial","20","bold"),justify='center')
jmeno.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

hrac_name=tk.Label(mainFrame,text='Hráč',justify="left")
hrac_name.grid(row=1,column=0)
pc_name=tk.Label(mainFrame,text="Počítač")
pc_name.grid(row=1,column=1)




hrac_f=tk.Frame(hlavni,relief="ridge",borderwidth=4)

#means that put hrac_f frame where is half(0.5, %50) of hlavni and and have width of %49 of hlavni.
#have %95 height of hlavni. We let a bit space at the edges so that we can see borders of frames.
hrac_f.place(relx=0.5,rely=0,relheight=0.95,relwidth=0.49)


Volba=tk.Label(hrac_f,text="Zadej svou volbu",font=("arial",10,"bold")).grid(row=0,column=0)
values=tk.Label(hrac_f,text="Vyber: Kámen, Nůžky, Papír",font=("arial",10)).grid(row=1,column=0)

choice_f=tk.Frame(hrac_f)
choice_f.grid(row=3,column=0)

stone=tk.Button(choice_f,text="kámen",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(0))
stone.grid(row=0,column=0)

scissors=tk.Button(choice_f,text="nůžky",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(1))
scissors.grid(row=0,column=1)

paper=tk.Button(choice_f,text="papír",relief="ridge",command=lambda: value_change(2))
paper.grid(row=0,column=2) 


hlavni.mainloop()
```

Comment: On right side could be inside of left side, but not on right side.

Comment: Yeap. However, in the question there is an  image of what he/she want to achieve. I coded acording to that.